# How to mock Delegate in xUnit

Tags: c#, .net-core, delegates, xunit

I have delegate that call `SendMessagesAsync` method which takes IEnumerable ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification. How I mock SendMessagesAsync that is callBack of delegate. In other word how I moq Delegate ?

`Interface`

```
public delegate Task<bool> SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications(IEnumerable<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification> exemptions);

public interface IRingGoApiService
{
    Task<RingGoMessageResponseResult> ProcessCreateRequestAsync(RingGoExemption ringGoExemption, SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications sendProviderExemption);
}
```

`Delegate Implementation`

```
public async Task<RingGoMessageResponseResult> ProcessCreateRequestAsync(RingGoExemption ringGoExemption, SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications sendProviderExemption)
    {
       var msgSent = await sendProviderExemption(new List<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification>() { exemption });
    }
```

`Test Class`

```
public MyTestClass{
 
public MyTestClass()
{
}

private readonly Mock<IProviderExemptionService> providerExemptionServiceMoq;
}
```

`using delegate`

```
var result = await _ringGoApiService.ProcessCreateRequestAsync(ringGoExemption,
async (IEnumerable<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification> exemptions) => await SendMessagesAsync(servicebusMessage, exemptions)
                    );
```

`SendMessagesAsync`

```
static async Task<bool> SendMessagesAsync(IAsyncCollector<Message> collector, IEnumerable<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification> exemptions)
    {
        SetProviderExemption(exemptions);

        var messages = exemptions.Select(exemption =>
        {
            //Creating ServiceBus Message...

            return message;
        });
    }

    static void SetProviderExemption(IEnumerable<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification> exemptions)
    {
        providerExemption = exemptions.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: You can't mock a delegate. But you can create a delegate in your test code that does whatever you want it to as long as it has the same signature as `SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications`, and pass that as a parameter into the method you're testing.

Comment: refer to section in my question `using delegate` there is lambda expression SendMessageAsync .. then how I mock that?

Comment: You cant mock that expression either since it is hard-coded into the expression., You need to capture the delegate in the callback and invoke it there. That is the only options available given the shown subject under test.

Comment: Can you kindly help me on syntax .. I am struggling on SendMessagesAsync(servicebusMessage, exemptions) callback in setup

Comment: ringGoApiServiceMoq.Setup(x => x.ProcessCreateRequestAsync(It.IsAny<RingGoExemption>(), It.IsAny<SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(ringGoMessageResponseResultMoq)
            .Callback(providerExemptionReceivedNotificationMoq));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mock a delegate. You cant mock that expression either since it is hard-coded into the subject under test.

You need to capture the delegate in a Moq `Callback` and invoke it there. That is the only option available given the shown subject under test.

Here is an oversimplified minimum reproducable example of a subject under test based on your previous posts.

```
public delegate Task<bool> SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications(IEnumerable<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification> exemptions);

public interface IRingGoApiService {
    Task<RingGoMessageResponseResult> ProcessCreateRequestAsync(RingGoExemption ringGoExemption, SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications sendProviderExemption);
}

public class RingGoMessageResponseResult { }

public class ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification { }

public class RingGoExemption : Exception { }

public interface IActionResult { }

public class OverSimplifiedExample {
    private readonly IRingGoApiService ringGoApiService;

    public OverSimplifiedExample(IRingGoApiService ringGoApiService) {
        this.ringGoApiService = ringGoApiService;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Run() {

        RingGoExemption ringGoExemption = new RingGoExemption();

        RingGoMessageResponseResult result = await ringGoApiService.ProcessCreateRequestAsync(ringGoExemption, myDelegate);

        return result != null;
    }

    private Task<bool> myDelegate(IEnumerable<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification> exemptions) {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

The test for the subject provided above, which includes the `Callback` capturing the delegate (handler) and invoking it, actually runs as expected when exercsed.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTestClass {
    [Test]
    public async Task MyTestMethod() {
        //Arrange
        Mock<IRingGoApiService> mock = new Mock<IRingGoApiService>();
        RingGoMessageResponseResult ringGoMessageResponseResult = new RingGoMessageResponseResult();

        mock
            .Setup(_ => _.ProcessCreateRequestAsync(It.IsAny<RingGoExemption>(), It.IsAny<SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(ringGoMessageResponseResult)
            .Callback((RingGoExemption exception, SendAnprProviderExemptionNotifications handler) => {
                var whateverMyExemptionsAre = Enumerable.Empty<ProviderExemptionReceivedNotification>();
                handler.Invoke(whateverMyExemptionsAre);
            });

        var subject = new OverSimplifiedExample(mock.Object);

        //Act
        var actual = await subject.Run();

        //Assert
        actual.Should().BeTrue();
    }
}
```

You will need to adapt this example to what you are trying to do. It won't copy exactly as written here.

You may still run into problem since you  have not shown what `SendMessagesAsync` is doing to ensure that a safe path can be mocked through its invocation.

Comment: Thanks alot for the support. I go through the code. I have also update question with SendMessagesAsync implementation

Comment: @Toxic what you basically need to do is make sure you mock all the dependencies that `SendMessageAsync` interacts with to allow the test to safely flow to completion.

Comment: Many thanks for the support. I have managed to make correct callBack